# How much does a holocron weigh?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition, star-wars, star-wars-d20, artifacts

Despite every D20 flavor of the Star Wars RPG dedicating several pages throughout multiple books to the subject of holocrons, not a single one of them appears to mention their weight. My gaming group makes inventory management a priority because our players typically prefer DEX-based character builds that dump STR, and carrying capacity is often used as the primary metric to reign in exactly how much STR a character can afford to dump. Therefore it is critical that we have accurate weights for desirable items, and holocrons are probably the single most desirable artifacts in the entire Star Wars universe.

Can anyone tell me, even roughly, how much a holocron is expected to weigh? I welcome any reliable source, including the now non-canon Expanded Universe material or references to the non-D20 flavors of the Star Wars RPG. I have already searched through my collection of Revised D20 and Saga Edition books as well as Wookiepedia and found nothing.

Comment: Would real-world approximations be sufficient? (Some folks 3D-print holocrons or otherwise make their own.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I would prefer such "evidence" be incorporated into an answer that also pulls from reliable sources as opposed to standing on its own merit. A 3D-printed holocron replica by itself would at best be derived from pure speculation without references to officially released technical specs, and most assuredly a reproduction would not be made of the same materials as a real holocron in-universe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approximately? Not a whole lot.**

Within canon and non-canon sources, holocrons are frequently seen being held easily in one hand or tossed around, implying that they do not weigh very much at all. My best guess would be less than 5lbs. Probably less than 1.

Holocrons appear to fit within a cube roughly 6 inches on a side and be made with a mostly hollow construction. The internals and externals appear to be made primarily of crystalline substances (kyber crystals, perhaps?) with a small lattice of metal holding the whole mass together. This would also seem to support the idea that holocrons are very light.

But honestly, all of that is an educated guess. There might be something in some of the setting guides, but the weight of a holocron is just not something that's described very often; if at all.

Comment: While I upvoted this answer, it leaves a lot to be desired - like a source citation - but seeing as it's the only entry so far, I'll mark it as the accepted answer until a better one comes along.

Comment: @Dyndrilliac What would you like me to provide sources for? You can find a few scenes of people interacting with a holocron in the Rebels TV series. They're also slathered throughout the comics and IIRC there's probably some in the video games as well.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't going to be able to find an accurate weight for holocrons since they don't have a standard size; they are made in differing shapes so their sizes will vary to a degree, but are still generally considered to be able to be held in one hand.  Even in Jedi Academy where they are listed, they aren't listed with a weight and its description isn't good enough to calculate an exact weight.  For in-game purposes the best way to determine its weight is to compare the weights of items of similar size.  A datapad would be a little smaller than a holocron at 0.5 kg, while a portable computer would be bigger at 2 kg so averaging it out to 1 kg would provide for a fair approximate weight that would fit its description.  Holocrons, though, are quite rare and provide little use in combat situations so unless you have no choice but to continuously carry a holocron with you, should you even have one in your possession, I would suggest not carrying it at all and leave it in a safe place, such as a ship if you have one.